# AttributeError: 'SolverStatus' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: pyomo

i got this error message when running an energy system optimization problem. Please any tips on how to resolve this?

> Blockquote

"Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\aadetunj\Desktop\oemof-examples-master\OSeEM-SN-main\scripting\scenarios\OSeEM-SN.py", line 318, in 
m.solve("cbc")

File "C:\Users\aadetunj\Anaconda3\envs\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\oemof\solph\models.py", line 204, in solve
status = solver_results["Solver"][0]["Status"].key

AttributeError: 'SolverStatus' object has no attribute 'key'

> Blockquote